# Problema com uma função JavaScript

Tags: jquery, addclass, hasclass

Estou com um problema aqui e não sei como resolver, em tese, na minha função abaixo de `768px` era para acrescentar a classe `.navbar-inverse` a tag `nav`, e acima de `768px` é para retirar ela caso exista, mas não acontece nada.

**Edit:** Eu fiz uns testes e vi que ele ta retirando SEMPRE essa classe e por isso ta dando problema.

Meu JS está assim:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
  var $element = $("nav");
    /*Abaixo de 768px, add a classe .navbar-inverse*/
  if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
      if(!$element.hasClass(".navbar-inverse")) {
          $element.addClass(".navbar-inverse")
        }
  }
    /* Acima de 768px, se existir a classe navbar-inverse ela é retirada*/

  if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
      if($element.hasClass(".navbar-inverse")) {
          $element.removeClass(".navbar-inverse")
      }
  } 
});
});
```

Eu não consigo ver o problema, a tag `nav` existe, mas nada acontece.

Comment: Se você redimensionar a tela funciona?

Comment: nope, n importa a resolução que eu redimensione a tela ele n funciona.

Comment: Embora as respostas atuais resolvam seu problema imediato, já considerou usar [*media queries*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries) em vez de ficar adicionando/removendo classes via JavaScript? (às vezes não dá pra evitar o JS, mas se for só uma questão de estilizar os componentes baseado na resolução da tela, uma solução CSS puro é preferível)

Comment: Já sim, eu uso, mas o layout estava bugando abaixo de 768px. Eu estou usando o bootstrap pra fazer o layout e pra fazer ficar bonito abaixo de 768px eu tinha que adicionar essa classe pra adaptar o layout pra usuários mobile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema é que `hasClass`, `addClass` e `removeClass` esperam o nome da classe, não um seletor. Portanto, não é para colocar o ponto no início. Fora isso, os `if`s que verificam se o elemento já tem a classe são desnecessários, e dá para otimizar a performance evitando procurar o elemento a todo momento. Eu faria assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $element = $("nav");
    $(window).resize(function () {    
        /*Abaixo de 768px, add a classe .navbar-inverse*/
        if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
            $element.addClass("navbar-inverse");
        /* Acima de 768px, se existir a classe navbar-inverse ela é retirada*/
        } else {
            $element.removeClass("navbar-inverse");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Obrigado! Mas agora eu estava pensando aqui com os meus botões, se uma pessoa entrar no site pelo celular ela n vai fazer o resize, ela vai entrar com uma resolução fixa, eu tentei chamar a lógica em uma função assim:  function trocaEstilo(){ mas não rolou, você teria alguma dica?

Comment: Eu acho que a melhor solução era usar media queries como o @mgibsonbr sugeriu lá em cima...

Comment: Eu ja tentei arrumar por Media Queries, mas buga muito e eu não consigo adicionar o botão. Então eu queria assim pq abaixo de 768px eu passaria para outro estilo do bootstrap pra chamar o botão de menu de um jeito que ele apareça.

Comment: @AndreyHartung Talvez valha a pena postar uma pergunta separada sobre o porquê de suas media queries bugarem.

Answer (score 4):

Retira o `.` do seletor jQuery nas funções `hasClass`, `addClass` e `removeClass`.

Experimenta:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).resize(function () {

        var $element = $("nav");

        /*Abaixo de 768px, add a classe .navbar-inverse*/
        if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
            if (!$element.hasClass("navbar-inverse")) {
                $element.addClass("navbar-inverse")
            }
        }

        /* Acima de 768px, se existir a classe navbar-inverse ela é retirada*/
        if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
            if ($element.hasClass("navbar-inverse")) {
                $element.removeClass("navbar-inverse")
            }
        }
    });
});
```